# How to execute query in Zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form, zend-db, zend-db-table

Thanks for previous replies

I am execution `"select Name from table_name where id=1";` . i saw some tutorials for getting data from the database, they mentioned `$DB = new Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql($params);
   DB->setFetchMode(Zend_Db::FETCH_OBJ);` and the result will getting through `$result = $DB->fetchAssoc($sql);` This $result is an array format, i want to get only name instead of getting all the data from the database. I am new to this topic. if i made any mistake pls do correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
$result = $DB->fetchOne("SELECT name FROM table_name WHERE id=1");
```

Answer (score 0):

> This code will execute your query through **doctrine** `getServiceLocator()`. With the help of `createQueryBuilder()`, you can write your query directly into zend-framework2, and with setParameter, any desired condition would be set easily.

```
$entityManager = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('doctrine.entitymanager.orm_default');
                $qb = $entityManager->createQueryBuilder();
                $qb->select(array(
                    'TableName.columnName as columnName '


                ))
                    ->from('ProjectName\Entity\TableName', 'TableName')
                    ->where('TableName.TableId = :Info')
                    ->setParameter('Info', $id);
                $var= $qb->getQuery()->getScalarResult();
```

The `$var` variable holds the value for which, you wanted the comparison to be made with, and holds only the single values of your interest.